# What is an electromagnetic plane wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, classical-electrodynamics

On Wikipedia:
In the physics of wave propagation, a plane wave (also spelled planewave) is a wave whose wavefronts (surfaces of constant phase) are infinite parallel planes.

In my understanding, an electromagnetic wave plane is an electric field perpendicular to a magnetic field which both form a surface plane that propagates in direction normal to the plane.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,in a plane emw the electric and magnetic field vectors oscillate in a plane, perpendicular to one another and the wave propagates in a direction perpendicular to that plane